# How to store MySql database connection string in C# WinFrom desktop application

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, connection-string

Keeping of `MySql` `connection` string with `server`, `user`, `password` and `database` data seems incorrect inside the code.

I see only two ways, how it can be stored, one is adding into `Resources` `.txt` like `string data = Properties.Resources.doc;`, but I'm not sure if it is secured method, another must be `.xml`, but I can't find any good guide, how to created such kind of access with `.xml` correctly, and  I'm also not sure if it is most proper way.

Any advice, guide or example would be useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard way to store a connection string in a WinForms application is creating an entry in the `connectionStrings` section inside the app.Config file.

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
         <add name="MyConnection" connectionString="Server=myServer;Database=myDatabase;
                                                    userid=root;password=pass;Port=3306"/>
    </connectionStrings>
    .....
</configuration>
```

Now you can retrieve this connection string in your code referencing the key named `MyConnection` using code like this:

```
string cnnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ConnectionString;
```

It is up to you to decide if you want to retrieve this info every time you need it or store it inside some kind of ad hoc in memory structure like a static MyAppConfig class

Comment: Hello, exactly what I was looking for, great support